# Unable to setup an Authenticator registration campaign in the Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication, azure-security, authenticator

I am trying to implement the 'registration campaign' feature in the azure portal. As outlined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-registration-campaign

My goal is to have users be prompted to register the Microsoft Authenticator app for passwordless sign-in. With these requirements:

- On their Initial sign in (where they reset their password)
- Without a manual step (like enabling a user for MFA in the portal), as I am creating users via the Graph API. Graph API calls to configure users are okay, Powershell is less desirable.
- Ideally, the user is able to defer the Authenticator sign-up
- Ideally, the user is not prompted to supply an MFA phone number

I have Security Defaults turned off, I have enabled Microsoft Authenticator and Email OTP authentication methods, I have enabled the registration campaign and currently I believe no forms of MFA turned on (but I had tried a few).

Working through the pre-requisites mentioned in the article I tried several configurations but was never able to get a new user prompted to register the Authenticator app. I will outline my confusion with the prerequisites:

**Prerequisite 1**

> Your organization must have enabled Azure AD Multi-Factor
> Authentication. Every edition of Azure AD includes Azure AD
> Multi-Factor Authentication. No additional license is needed for a
> registration campaign.

- It seems there are multiple ways to enable MFA, and it isn't clear which methods are appropriate.
- I tried adding MFA on all sign-ins with conditional access, and it didn't seem to have an effect. Also, wouldn't doing this defeat the purpose of using the Authenticator app? and it's unclear which MFA option I should be using.
- I don't think that I want MFA enabled through security defaults (again, trying to avoid using phone number) or via Identity Protection (seems to be superseded by conditional access)
- There also appears to be an MFA server, but I am assuming that this is not applicable, so I have ignored it.
- Is there another place to enable MFA?

**Prerequisite 2**

> Users can't have already set up the Authenticator app for push
> notifications on their account.

- This shouldn't be an issue as this is a new environment and I haven't registered any Authenticator apps yet.

**Prerequisite 3a**

> Admins need to enable users for the Authenticator app using one of
> these policies:
>
> - MFA Registration Policy: Users will need to be enabled for Notification through mobile app.

- I believe this is referring to the Multifactor authentication registration policy in Identity Protection, but I enabled it and it didn't seem to have an effect.
- Perhaps this is referring to something else?

**Prerequisite 3b**

> - Authentication Methods Policy: Users will need to be enabled for the
>   Authenticator app and the Authentication mode set to Any or Push. If
>   the policy is set to Passwordless, the user won't be eligible for the
>   nudge. For more information about how to set the Authentication mode,
>   see Enable passwordless sign-in with Microsoft Authenticator.

- I have enabled the 'Microsoft Authenticator' Authentication Method Policy with 'Any' mode, but I am unsure if it is in effect.
- According to the azure portal I may require 'combined registration' be turned on: '*If your tenant doesn’t yet use combined security info registration, turn it on now – it’s required to use this policy.*' Following the documentation, I am unable to figure out where and how I can see if this feature is enabled or not. This document appears like it should tell me but it does not: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-registration-mfa-sspr-combined
- Perhaps 'combined registration' being the new default means it's always on? and that authentication methods should be working? but then why would it present that message?
- What does it mean by '*Users will need to be enabled...*'? The whole point of this feature is to have the user enable the authenticator app when they sign in right?

Perhaps there is a guide somewhere to set this up? I've only found instructions beginning at the point where the prerequisites have been met.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that: To setup registration campaign, the users must have MFA enabled.

For testing, I **enabled MFA** for only one user like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Users -> Click on Per-user MFA*

[image]

Now, I **enabled registration campaign** in the Azure portal like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Security -> Authentication methods -> Policies -> Click on Microsoft Authenticator*

[image]

Click on **Registration campaign**, edit and save like below:

*You can select All users; I added only one user for testing.*

[image]

After the above configuration, I tried to login with the user like below:

I configured phone authentication for user:

[image]

After entering the code, **I got the screen to setup Authenticator app successfully** like below:

[image]

I configured the Authenticator App;

[image]

After successfully configuration while signing in, **I got the screen to Approve sign in request** like below:

[image]

To **enable MFA for all the users**, you can make use of bulk update option like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini , when I enabled specific users, I do see this working, with mixed success. But I'm afraid you've omitted three key points I'm looking for: 1. I'd like the user to be prompted on their first sign in. 2. I'd like to not be prompted for a phone number. 3. Since I'm creating the users via Graph API, I'd like to not have a manual step to enable their MFA  (I'll update my description with these)

Comment: AFAIK MFA is required to enable approve request screen

Answer (score 0):

Everyone forgot Registration campaign is NOT for passwordless..

"Can users be nudged to set up passwordless phone sign-in?

The feature aims to empower admins to get users set up with MFA using the Authenticator app and not passwordless phone sign-in."

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/how-to-mfa-registration-campaign#frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well. I believe the reason the authenticator campaign doesn't kick in as expected, is because Security Defaults is disabled and without security defaults OR a P1/P2 license, you are working with a **feature-limited version of MFA and Conditional Access** (MFA-Lite if you will) which do not offer the authenticator registration campaign.

If you were to enable Security Defaults or enable MFA/CA with a P1 or P2 license, the Authenticator Registration campaign would trigger for those users it is assigned to.